# creating Wiki family on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-computer, mediawiki

I'm a new user of `Ubuntu`.

[Here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family#Giant_switch_statement) you can see:

> This will allow you to install more than one wiki on a single **server**,
>   using the same source code checkout.

Also in [Manual:FAQ](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ) you can see:

> It is possible to install more than one wiki on a **server** provided
>   that:
>
> You use a different database for each wiki Or
>
> You use a different database prefix for each wiki (for Postgres, you
>   can achieve a similar effect by using different schemas and users)

Now is it possible to setup Wiki family on `Ubuntu` **`desktop`** `14.04`?

Comment: Try reading the [FAQ](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ). In particular "How do I install MediaWiki using a package?"

Comment: @DavidPostill If you search in the page that you referenced, you can only links to the page that I referenced in my question. So you can see why I did not find that page helpful .

Comment: What is not helpful about the detailed instructions on that page?

Comment: @DavidPostill In that page you can see any thing about `desktop OS`. Not in about possibility or impossibility.

Comment: <sigh>. Please read [Manual:Installation requirements](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Installation_requirements): "A web server is required to serve the requested pages to the client browser." ... "Most installations use the Apache web server,".

Comment: Simple one-download installation: "Use XAMPP from http://www.apachefriends.org to install and configure all of the important packages – Apache web server, PHP, and MySQL database – with only one download. It is available for Linux, Windows, Mac and Solaris. As of August 2015, the latest version of XAMPP includes PHP 5.6.12 (MediaWiki requires at least 5.3.3)."

Comment: [HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html): "

The Apache2 web server is available in Ubuntu Linux. To install Apache2:

    At a terminal prompt enter the following command:

    sudo apt-get install apache2

"

Comment: @DavidPostill OK! I think you mean when I could install MediaWiki, I have a `server` and I can use that to setup a `Wiki Family` and it does not need to install on `Ubuntu server`. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. You need a web server installed (like apache), not an OS server install.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you very much for your attention and time!